# Is rft capable of reading object inside a panel

Tags: java, rft

I am working with rational functional tester8.1 and I am unable to read the objects inside a panel (.Net application) so please help me

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Mano

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mapping the objects dynamically? Get the panel object, then try calling getMappableChildren() on it to see if the objects show up.